# Unable to "captureVisibleTab" on a chrome-created tab, even though all permissions are set properly

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I've been working on an extension that takes a screenshot of your active tab and allows you to annotate it.

In my background script, I'm able to successfully use "captureVisibleTab" and send a dataURI to my content script and render it in a new chrome tab.

But when I need to take a second screenshot within the newly created chrome tab, I send a message to the background script to take a screenshot, and then I'm getting this error:

`Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-extension://pgcahhckfdfpkjbbnblmabcbobbnmfie/comment.html". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.`

I've done many, many searches on each part of this error, and all of them told me to do things (all of which I've tried) such as:

- Add  to my manifest.json
- Add "activeTab" and "tabCapture" and "tabs" to my manifest permissions
- Tried using chrome.tabCapture instead

But in all cases, it doesn't seem to like that I'm trying to capture a visible tab, even though the tab is a chrome extension tab (formatted like `chrome-extension://pgcahhckfdfpkjbbnblmabcbobbnmfie/comment.html`)

I've also tried adding that chrome-extension URL to my permissions and to web-accessible resources, but neither of those things work either.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I've been debugging this for hours and I really don't know what else to try or what else I could be missing.

Comment: See https://crbug.com/839857

Comment: I've found this and read through it all. Does this mean all I can do is wait until Chrome fixes this? I don't know how else I'm supposed to take a screenshot of a `chrome-extension` page using the chrome API.

Comment: Well, other than waiting, which is obvious but useless, you can try to rework the extension to do the stuff right inside the web page using the content script and DOM manipulation.